# How to add a custom library to GCC while compliling?

Tags: c, gcc, compilation

i have downloaded a C library from the net with the name libsal.a, to access the APIs in that library i   include a header file by name #include  in my main.c. i use the following command to compile it :

```
gcc -L /home/traana/Desktop/opensal-1.0.0/libsal.a main.c
```

but get the following error when i compile

```
main.c:3:17: fatal error: sal.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

How do I do this correctly?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When compiling your source, it's not the library, but the include files that are relevant; so you'll need to tell gcc where those are, something like

```
gcc -c -I/home/traana/Desktop/opensal-1.0.0/include main.c
```

and then link the application with something like

```
gcc -L/home/traana/Desktop/opensal-1.0.0 -lsal main.o
```

Answer (score 10):

I believe that there are three arguments that you will need to set:

```
-I <include directory>
-L <library directory>
-l <library name>
```

The include directory will be location of the header files. The library directory will be the location of the library (.a or .so), and the library name will be the name of the library file, without the leading 'lib' prefix or its extension (i.e.  -lsal rather than -l libsal.a ).

Answer (score 0):

if the *.h are in  /home/traana/Desktop/opensal-1.0.0

try

```
 gcc -I /home/traana/Desktop/opensal-1.0.0 -L /home/traana/Desktop/opensal-1.0.0 main.c -lsal
```

Comment: there should not be any space after -I and -L